# Is there a way to change the alpha value of the x/y ticks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, figure

I am wanting to change the alpha value of the color of the x ticks. I understand how to change the color of the xticks (see below), but am not sure how to change the alpha value. Is this possible? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which=u'both',length=3, color="red")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a 4-tuple, where the last one represents alpha channel:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which=u'both',length=3, color=[1,0,0,0.5])
```

Or you can pass a hex code:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which=u'both',length=5, color='#FF000080')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That does exactly what I'm looking for. Had no idea it was possible to do it using the 4-tuple. I've upvoted your answer and marked it as accepted. Thanks again!